# Roots of $ x^3-3x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

How can I find the roots of $x^3-3x+1$ using Cardano's formula?

So far, I found that

$$x = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}}$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{-3}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{-3}}{2}}$$

I am now trying to express each cubic radicand in their exponential form.

Euler's formula : $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.

I have $r = |z| = 1$.

However, when I try to find the angle, I get

$$\theta = \arccos \frac{-1}{2} = 2\pi/3$$

but at the same time

$$\theta = \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2} = \pi/3$$

Shouldn't the two angles be the same for one radicand?

Plus, once I will have expressed the two radicands in their exponential form, what is the next step?

$$x = \sqrt[3]{e^{i2\pi/3}} + \sqrt[3]{e^{i4\pi/3}}$$
$$x = e^{i2\pi/9} + e^{i4\pi/9}$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ for all $x$. In particular
$$\sin\frac\pi3=\sin\frac{2\pi}3.$$ Another time you may need to use $\cos x=\cos(-x)$ instead. The arcus functions are not "reliable" because of these.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you! What can I do next? I don't know any property of the exponential function $e+e = $ somehting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Cardano approach:

Let
$$ x=u+v $$ then we will get

$$u^3+v^3+3(uv-1)(u+v)+1=0$$

by setting $uv-1=0$ we get $$uv=1$$ and $$u^3+v^3=-1$$ by cubing the first equation we obtain a simple quadratic system in terms of $u^3$ and $v^3$ which you can be reduced to a quadratic equation in terms of $u^3$ for example: $$u^3+\frac{1}{u^3}+1=0$$

Then use the Quadratic formula to find $u^3$ and $v^3=-1-u^3$

After extracting cubic roots of the obtained solution you need to take into account that $uv$ is real. This will give the appropriate pairs of $u$ and $v$ whose sums will yield all three roots of the equation.

Comment: I think this is what I used. $u^3 = \dfrac{-q+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$ and $v^3 = \dfrac{-q-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}$